# Wrong url enter when pushing on github, how to enter the correct one?

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I am committing my android project through VCS available in android studio

[This is how I do it.](https://www.londonappdeveloper.com/how-to-use-git-hub-with-android-studio/)

However I was  asked to enter the url when I came to push window and I entered a wrong one. The push got rejected. I went through many stack overflow threads and tried setting the url in vain.

I am new androd studio and even new to git hub. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on doing it through android studio

I used Git bash and with help of an experienced developer

This is what I did with the developer's directions

git rm remote origin

rm -rf .git

ls -a

git status

git init

git remote add origin https://[My path]

git add .

git commit -m "initialcimmit"

git pull origin master

vim .gitignore

git add .

git commit -m "initialcimmit"

git push origin master